# Class Linearization not working in scala 2.13

Tags: scala, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to upgrade scala 2.12 to scala 2.13.5

Class linearization is not properly working for me, IntelliJ and Scala compiler throws an error but ideally it should work. Below is the problem.

```
trait A[E] {
  def getObject: E = {
    // some implementation
  }
}

abstract class B[T](e: Object) {
  def getObject: T = {
    // some implemntation
  }
}

class C[T] extends B[T](null) with A[String] {
  
  def myMethod(): Unit = {
    println(this.getObject.someMethodWhichIsNotInStringClassButAvailableInTClass)
  }
}
```

In the above sample program as well, `this.getObject` is coming from `A` where I'm expecting it to come from `B`. Looks like my understanding is wrong. But need to understand this class [linearization](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/05-classes-and-objects.html#class-linearization) problem in detail.

Because of the above issue, my code is not compiling as the required method is not available in `String` class.

*Also the same code compiles with scala 2.12 but not with scala 2.13.5.*

Another reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49832570/819866

Comment: Weird but you code work for Scala 2.13 in Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/6xi5ySqISjm3N6niX84Pfw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not compile at all ... and it indeed does not for me (2.13.1):

```
       error: class C inherits conflicting members:
         def getObject: T (defined in trait B) and
         def getObject: String (defined in trait A)
         (note: this can be resolved by declaring an `override` in class C.)
```

You cannot inherit different methods with the same name.

Also, if your inheritance was actually valid, linearization would still work left to right:

```
    trait A { def foo: Sting }
    trait B extends A { def foo = "b" }
    trait C extends A { def foo = "c" }
    class D extends B with C

    println(new D().foo)
```

This prints "c".

Comment: Okay. This might be introduced in scala 2.13 since same works for 2.12. Also, I forgot to mention that both of the method `getObject` is declared as `final` in traits because of which overriding them is also not working.

Comment: Should I create a new method with a different name and then call the correct method using `super[ClassType].getObject` as a workaround? Also, is this the correct solution for this problem?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know about 2.12 ... if it indeed worked there, it was a bug. This should not work.

Comment: The correct solution is to not give different methods the same name :)

Comment: They are coming from libraries actually, project is dependent on `Apache Wicket` one `getObject` is coming from `LoadableDetachableModel<T>` and another one is coming from `IModel<E>`. They both have same name and same signature. I have no control over it.

Comment: Well, I don't know that library. But evidently, those two traits are not intended to be mixed in together.

Comment: Okay thank you for your help. If it was a bug in 2.12 then, my project inheritance is actually heavily dependent on this bug. Facing this problem in many places. I'll use my workaround of creating a method with different name and will use it. Thanks again!

Comment: I am not sure how you are planning on using that "workaround":  you cannot create a class that extends both those traits to begin with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230475/discussion-between-sunil-kumar-and-dima).